# *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x096fb008 *** Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, corruption, double-free

I am getting the error same as the title. I think it is happening because of matrix A but can't understand why and how to fix it.

Kindly help me out. Here is the complete code. I am using g++ to compile the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void count()
{
    FILE *file, *output, *list;
    file = fopen("coordinate", "r");
    output = fopen("number", "w");
    list = fopen("list", "w");
    int min;
    printf("Enter the minimum number of atoms for critical clusters :");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    int i, j, count=0, cnt=0, fin_count=0, id;
    int nmonomer= 165;
    double x, y, z, sumx, sumy, sumz, sum=0;
    char dump[1000];
    while (fgets(dump, 1000, file)!=NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(dump)==1)
            count++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("%d\n",count);
    file = fopen("coordinate", "r");
    int clus_cnt[count];
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        clus_cnt[i] = 0;
    while (fgets(dump, 1000, file)!=NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(dump)==1)
        {
            fprintf(list, "%5d%5d\n", (cnt+1), clus_cnt[cnt]);
            cnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(list, "%s", dump);
            clus_cnt[cnt]++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(list);
    file = fopen("list", "r");
    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (clus_cnt[i] >= min)
        {
            sumx=0;
            sumy=0;
            sumz=0;
            for (j=0; j<clus_cnt[i]; j++)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%lf%lf%lf\n", &x, &y, &z);
                sumx += x;
                sumy += y;
                sumz += z;
            }
            //fprintf (output, "%8d%8d%12.3f%12.3f%12.3f\n", i+1, clus_cnt[i], sumx, sumy, sumz);
            fprintf (output, "%5d%5d%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f\n", i+1, clus_cnt[i], sumx/(double)clus_cnt[i], sumy/(double)clus_cnt[i], sumz/(double)clus_cnt[i]);
            fgets(dump, 1000, file);
            fin_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            for (j=0; j<clus_cnt[i]+1; j++)
                fgets(dump, 1000, file);
        }       
    }
    printf("%d\n", fin_count);
    fclose(file);
    fclose(output);
    file = fopen("number", "r");    
    for (i=0; i<fin_count; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d%d%lf%lf%lf\n", &id, &cnt, &x, &y, &z);
        sum += cnt;
    }
    sum /= (double)fin_count;
    printf ("The Average Number of Clusters :%8.3f\n", sum);
    fclose(file);
}
int main()
{
    FILE *file, *output, *coords, *selection;
    file = fopen("dump.sti", "r");
    output = fopen("cluster_list", "w");
    coords = fopen("coordinate", "w");
    double cutoff;
    printf("Enter the cutoff distance :");
    scanf("%lf",&cutoff);
    int i, natom=8122, nmonomer=165, nstep=9, id, type, index=0, j, lk, mol, k, sel, s;
    double xs, ys, zs, xi, yi, zi, x[nmonomer], y[nmonomer], z[nmonomer], xj, yj, zj, vx, vy, vz, dist, rxk, ryk, rzk, q;
    int l[nmonomer], ind[nmonomer], flag[nmonomer];
    char dump[1000];
    int A[8122];
    for (i=0; i<8122; i++)
    { fscanf(file, "%d%d%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf\n", &id, &type, &xs, &ys, &zs, &xi, &yi, &zi);
      A[i] = type;
    }
    fclose(file);
    for (s=0; s<natom; s++)
    {
        selection = fopen("selection_fxfg", "r");
    fscanf(file, "%d%d%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf\n", &id, &type, &xs, &ys, &zs, &xi, &yi, &zi);
        for (i=0; i<nmonomer; i++)
        {
              fscanf(selection, "%d", &sel);    
              if (id == sel)
              {
                x[index] = xs + (46.1206 + 40.1206)*xi;
                y[index] = ys + (86.8457 + 56.8457)*yi;
                z[index] = zs + (35.9228 + 35.9228)*zi;
                ind[index] = id;   
                index++;
              }
        }
       fclose(selection);
     }

    printf("%d\n", index);
    //-------------
    for (i=0; i<nmonomer; i++)
        l[i] = i;
    for (i=0; i<nmonomer-1; i++)
    {
        if (i == l[i])
        {
            j=i;
            xj = x[j];
            yj = y[j];
            zj = z[j];
            for (k=i+1; k<nmonomer; k++)
            {
                lk = l[k];
                if (lk == k)
                {
                    rxk = xj-x[k];
                    ryk = yj-y[k];
                    ryk = yj-y[k];
                    rzk = zj-z[k];
                    dist = sqrt(pow(rxk,2)+pow(ryk,2)+pow(rzk,2));
                    if (dist <= cutoff)
                    {
                        l[k] = l[j];
                        l[j] = lk;
                    }
                }
            }
            j = l[j];
            xj = x[j];
            yj = y[j];
            zj = z[j];
            while (j != i)
            {
                for (k=i+1; k<nmonomer; k++)
                {
                    lk = l[k];
                    if (lk == k)
                    {
                        rxk = xj-x[k];
                        ryk = yj-y[k];
                        rzk = zj-z[k];
                        dist = sqrt(pow(rxk,2)+pow(ryk,2)+pow(rzk,2));
                        if (dist <= cutoff)
                        {
                            l[k] = l[j];
                            l[j] = lk;
                        }
                    }
                }
                j = l[j];
                xj = x[j];
                yj = y[j];
                zj = z[j];
            }
        }
    }
    //-------------
    for (i=0; i<nmonomer; i++)
    {
        flag[i] = 0;
        fprintf(output, "%8d%8d\n", i+1, l[i]+1);
    }

    int lit;
    for (i=0; i<nmonomer; i++)
    {
        if (flag[i] == 0)
        {
            lit = l[i];
            if (lit != i)
            {
                fprintf(coords, "%10.3f %10.3f %10.3f%d\n", x[i], y[i], z[i],A[i]);
                while (lit != i)
                {
                    flag[lit] = 1;
                    fprintf(coords, "%10.3f %10.3f %10.3f%d\n", x[lit], y[lit], z[lit], A[lit]);
                    lit = l[lit];
                }
                fprintf(coords, "\n");
            }
            else
                fprintf(coords, "%10.3f %10.3f %10.3f%d\n\n", x[i], y[i], z[i], A[i]);          
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(output);
    fclose(coords);
    count();
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Ah!! I'd love to help you but this is too long to read. Try removing non essential part of the code and repost. The more precise you are, the more likely you will get an answer. And who knows with this exercise you might solve your own problem yourself!

Comment: Scientific computing in C++? You must love pain.

Comment: If you are using `gcc`, compile with `-g` and use `gdb` to debug your program and help narrow down errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have a call to `fclose(file)` in the middle of main, but continue to read from it and close it again at the end of main.

Two calls to fclose on the same file handle may cause a double-free error (or may do something else entirely in a different run).

Answer (score 1):

just remove line 102

```
fclose(file);
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, it should explain the problem.